# How to serialize two 'has_one' model using activerecord

Tags: active-model-serializers

I have two has_one models (from_airport and to_airport) which gets its values from the model 'airport'.

How do i embed the ids of from_airport and to_airport and include the airport objects
using active model serializers and also include the airport object using active model serializer.